# Not able to fetch value of a text box

Tags: jquery

Not able to fetch value of a text box

I am trying following code

```
 $(document).on('focusout', '.barcode', function(event){
                event.preventDefault();

                var pid=$(this).parents('.row').attr('id');
                alert(pid);
                var bcd=$(pid+' .barcode').val();
                alert($(pid+' .barcode'));
                alert(bcd);
                var datastr='barCode='+bcd;
                alert(datastr);
           });
```

I am trying it for following html

```
<tr class="row" id="item10">
                                    <td><input type="text" name="barcode" class="barcode" style="width: 50px"/></td>
                                    <td><input type="text" name="type" class="type" style="width: 50px"/></td>
                                    <td><input type="text" name="color" class="color" style="width: 50px"/></td>
                                    <td><input type="text" name="qty" class="qty" style="width: 50px"/></td>
                                    <td><input type="text" name="price" class="price" style="width: 50px"/></td>

                                </tr>


   value of var `id` is correct but `bcd` and `dataStr` is not correct.
```

Please see what is the problem

Comment: Please use consistent indentation for your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing "#" id indicator

```
var bcd=$("#"+pid+' .barcode').val();
```

or

```
var pid="#"+$(this).parents('.row').attr('id');
```

And `<tr>` must be wrapped with `<table>` incase yours isn't.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/khn5c/)

Answer (score 2):

```
       $(document).on('focusout', '.barcode', function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            alert($(this).val());
       });
```

you can just use $(this).val() to get value of that element

Comment: +1 didn't think of that ^^ i was too focused on fixing his code

Answer (score 0):

Also, is you code inside a

```
$(document).ready(function () {
......
});
```

Comment: It doesn't have to be since he's using $(document).on('